# How to filter data by custom field of custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, filter, taxonomy

I have created a custom taxonomy 'vendor' with some custom field 'address'.
And registered this taxonomy with post type 'product'.
Now i want to list all products with same address.

Comment: where have you stored the values of the custom taxonomy custom fields?

Comment: The values of custom taxonomy gets stored in tables 'wp_terms' and 'wp_term_taxonomy'.
custom field address is stored in 'wp_options' table.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to start the listing, first run a query to select all the taxonomies(vendor) which have that address. Then after that is done you will have the ids of all the terms and then use that array of terms in wp_query and pass them in the tax_query parameter.

Comment: hey thanks.
I am getting the correct result by tax_query. but I am not getting how can I pass this data to woocommerce 'shop' page.
I mean how to display these products on shop page.

Comment: is it mandatory that you need to do this on woocommerce shop page? if not then you could create a custom page and run the query there and list products easily. If yes then i guess its quite some work which needs modification help of a developer